# How to preserve the white space in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I am working on XML with **actionscript 3** and **Flex 4**. For my XML, I have to set *prettyPrinting* and *ignoreWhitespace* properties are false. But when I set these two properties as false, it perserve the whitespace except first line.

```
    <text id="1">
  <P>
    <FONT>
      <B>      ftesting 123</B>
    </FONT>
  </P>
  <P>
    <FONT>
      <B>                     </B>
    </FONT>
  </P>
</text>
```

I got the following for the above code,

```
<text id="1">//First line space is not preserved
  <P>
    <FONT>
      <B>      ftesting 123</B>
    </FONT>
  </P>
  <P>
    <FONT>
      <B>                     </B>
    </FONT>
  </P>
</text>
```

And if I give the input like this

```
    <text id="1"><P><FONT><B>      ftesting 123</B></FONT></P><P><FONT><B>                     </B></FONT></P></text>
```

I got the output like this

```
<text id="1"><P><FONT><B>      ftesting 123</B></FONT></P><P><FONT><B>                     </B></FONT></P></text>
```

But I want output like this

```
<text id="1">
  <P>
    <FONT>
      <B>      ftesting 123</B>
    </FONT>
  </P>
  <P>
    <FONT>
      <B>                     </B>
    </FONT>
  </P>
</text>
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your spaces you should write your text in a CDATA tag, it will be considered as text and not as XML (with stripable whitespaces):

```
<text id="1"><![CDATA[<B>      test</B>]]></text>
```

Comment: My code is working well except the first line. Please see my code. And I have to get input as a XML file. Then how can I use CDATA?

Comment: Did you try putting everything in a CDATA? Even your first line

Comment: your answer is right for my first requirement. Thank you so much for that. Can you have any idea about my second requirement?

Comment: No, sorry, you will need to develop your own XML indenting function, or find one online. This cannot be done natively by AS3.